# ActiveStorage order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

Is there a way to order the blobs in `ActiveStorage`?

The following works

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :attachments, as: :attachable


  scope :with_attached_files, ->  { includes(:attachments).merge(Attachment.with_attached_file.order('active_storage_blobs.filename')) }
end
```

However, it is case sensitive.

I have tried

```
  scope :with_attached_files, ->  { includes(:attachments).merge(Attachment.with_attached_file.order(Arel.sql('lower(active_storage_blobs.filename)'))) }
```

but it generates a SQL error.

> PG::UndefinedTable - ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table
>   "active_storage_blobs"

The generated query is

> SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."slug" = $1
>   ORDER BY lower(active_storage_blobs.filename) LIMIT $2  [["slug",
>   "aa0001-18"], ["LIMIT", 1]]

My current idea is to overwrite the default scope on `ActiveStorageBlob` but it doesn't seem to work so far.

Comment: Hi, can you please paste the SQL error?

Comment: Sure. see updated question.